# Why does this math function return different values in Java and JavaScript?

Tags: java, javascript, math

This JavaScript code returns 115.3:

```js
function FV(rate, nper, pmt, pv, type) {
    var pow = Math.pow(1 + rate, nper);
    var fv;
    if (rate) {
        fv = (pmt*(1+rate*type)*(1-pow)/rate)-pv*pow;
    } else {
        fv = -1 * (pv + pmt * nper);
    }
    return fv.toFixed(2);
}

document.write(   FV(0.06/12,12,-(2750+1375)/12,-0,0)-(0+2750+1375)    )
```

This Java code returns 106.1:

```
public double FV(double rate, double nper, double pmt, double pv, int type) {
    double pow = Math.pow(1 + rate, nper);
    double fv;        
    if (rate > 0) {
        fv = (pmt*(1+rate*type)*(1-pow)/rate)-pv*pow;
    } else {
        fv = -1 * (pv + pmt * nper);
    }
    return fv;
}
System.out.println(FV(0.06/12,12,-(2750+1375)/12,-0,0)-(0+2750+1375));
```

They look the same to me, but they return different values. What's wrong?

Comment: Default type of Java `integer` literals `int` and int devision round up the value. whereas in javascript devision operator return value dynamically, ex. `1 / 2      // returns 0.5 in JavaScript` and `1 / 2      // returns 0 in Java`

Comment: @SubhrajyotiMajumder Integer division rounds towards zero. The [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.17.2) says this about it: `Integer division rounds toward 0. That is, the quotient produced for operands n and d that are integers after binary numeric promotion (§5.6.2) is an integer value q whose magnitude is as large as possible while satisfying |d · q| ≤ |n|. Moreover, q is positive when |n| ≥ |d| and n and d have the same sign, but q is negative when |n| ≥ |d| and n and d have opposite signs.`

Comment: I am saying same @kobit

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In JavaScript `-(2750+1375)/12` evaluates to `-343.75`. In Java it evaluates to `-343`, because in Java when you divide integer numbers, you get integer result. To fix this simply replace the expression with `-(2750+1375)/12.0`.